# How to retain visibly previous uploaded files using ng-file-upload when tried to upload again?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, upload, ng-file-upload

I have implemented ng-file-upload directive to upload my files to the respective URL.....for now when I select a file both upload and select is happening simultaneously according to the functionality of ng-file-upload.

But,After the upload when i try to again upload certain other files....the previously uploaded files are vanishing visibly.....i want to retain the previous uploaded files too and need to get the newly uploaded files below those...how can work on this?

My html

```
<form>
         <input type="text" class="browse-form"placeholder="   Click browse to load documents " required>
         <button ngf-select="vm.uploadFiles($files)" multiple accept=".csv,.pdf,.doc,.docx,.xlsx" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Browse</button>
        </form>
        <p style="margin-top: -30px;"> Note:Supported file formats are word,excel and pdf only</p>
        <table class="table table-fixed">
         <thead class="table-header"><tr>
         <th class="col-xs-6">DOCUMENT NAME</th>
         <th class="col-xs-1">SIZE</th>
         <th class="col-xs-1">VERSION</th>
         <th class="col-xs-2">DATE UPLOADED</th>
         <th class="col-xs-2">UPLOADED BY</th>
         <th class="col-xs-1">ACTION</th></tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         <tr ng-repeat="uploading in vm.files track by $index" style="font:smaller">
         <td>{{uploading.name}}</td>
```

MY controller.js

```
 vm.uploadFiles = function(files){
 vm.files = files;
 angular.forEach(files,function(file){
  file.upload = Upload.upload({
      url:' ', 
      data:{file:file}
  });

  file.upload.then(function(response){
      $timeout(function(){
          file.result = response.data;
      });
      },

  function (response) {
      if (response.status > 0)
          vm.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
  },

  function (evt) {
      file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
  });});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you create an array and push to it each time file is uploaded

```
vm.fileArr = []

vm.uploadFiles = function(files) {


    vm.files = files;

    angular.forEach(files, function(file) {

        vm.fileArr.push(file)// show this array 

        file.upload = Upload.upload({
            url: ' ',
            data: {
                file: file
            }
        });
        file.upload.then(function(response) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    file.result = response.data;
                });
            },
            function(response) {
                if (response.status > 0)
                    vm.errorMsg = response.status + ': ' + response.data;
            },
            function(evt) {
                file.progress = Math.min(100, parseInt(100.0 * evt.loaded / evt.total));
            });
    });
}
```

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="uploading in vm.fileArr track by $index>.....i displayed something like this im not able to get the array content into my HTML....strange...it goes undefined...:|@sachila ranawaka

Comment: the logic of retaining previous uploaded files works in a controller by pushing it to the array....but still display into HTML goes undefined...i tried inside foreach loop too@sachila ranawaka

Comment: can you create a demo

Comment: @HKI345 - can you post example code of the solution that worked for you?  I too am facing similar problem - retaining previously uploaded files without them disappearing.  I'm also experiencing them being removed on successful upload and want to see your example as it working.  Thanks

Comment: @SouthPlatte the example code js is have mentioned in the solution above,you just need to push the uploaded files into an Array and make that array to display in your HTML code....your previous uploaded files will be stored in that array has you are uploading your new files...logic lies in an array...sorry for the late reply:)